# What is variable f supposed to contain in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I try to see what is the logic behind a jQuery plugin, and I am stacked with the following issue.

I have the following code, and I cannot determine what should be the value of the var `f` inside the variable `t = function(u, a){}`

```
(
    function($)
    {                            
        $.fn.pluginName = function(userOptions)
        {

            ...

            if((typeof userOptions).match("object|undefined"))
            {
                return this.each(
                    function(e)
                    {
                        new t(this, userOptions)
                    }
                );
            }

            var t = function (u, a)
            {
                var f = this;
            }

            ...

        }
    }
)(jQuery)
```

It should contain a reference in function `t` or it should has a reference on `pluginName`

Can somebody to help me with that ? I am totaly confused with that.

Comment: We can't tell with the code you posted. The value of `this` in js changes depending on how the function is called. Can you post how `t` is called?

Comment: Yes, give me a sec, and I will post that information right now

Comment: @GregL the code has heen updated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that function `t` is a constructor function, which means that `this` inside the function will refer to the instance that is created when that function is invoked with the `new` keyword.

Therefore `f` will refer to the instance of the object whose constructor is function `t`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @GregL. Your answer was very valuable for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

When I want to find out what `this` is I simply print it with `console.log(this);`
to increase readability you can add toStrings (to the object or its prototype).

In addition I think GregL has it right in this example. But it's a strange example you have provided when trying to figure out this. Some names to the constructor function and actually saving the object created using new in a variable would help GregLs explaination make sense

Comment: This is what I am doing too, but currently I am not debuging the plugin on my browser. I have the plugin source code and I try to understand what it does, and how it does it. Anyway, thanks a lot for your response :)